# Python Iterating through excel file to find information

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, text

Python for Data analyst. I'm parsing an excel document with thousands of entries. thus far, I've got code to change the excel to a csv, copy paste the entire document into a text file that is '|' explicitely serparted instead of coma separated. Unfortunately, the data is missing information and I only want to copy and paste information from those that have a certain column entry that is a number ranging from 0 to 999. Please help me write a code that will iterate/go through rows and search for a number ranging 0 to 999. If found, I want to go ahead and copy/paste that entry and 3 other columns in that row. If not found, please tell the code to skip to the next row instead of copying any information from columns of that row. This is to be copied into a text file.

```
import pandas as pd
import os.path as op

def extract_export_columns(df, list_of_columns, file_path):
    column_df = df[list_of_columns]
    column_df.to_csv(file_path, index=False, sep="|")
#Orrginal file
    input_base_path = 'C:somewhere'
    main_df_data_file = pd.read_csv(op.join(input_base_path, 'somewhere '))

#Product of code
    output_base_path = r'C:somewhere'
    extract_export_columns(main_df_data_file,
                        ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'etc'],
                        op.join(output_base_path, 'something.txt'))

    extract_export_columns(main_df_data_file,
                        ['column7'],
                        op.join(output_base_path, 'some_other_thing.txt'))
```

Comment: It would help if you added a short worked CSV example showing input and expected output.

Comment: Hello Sir, @martinevans

Comment: Note: You can use the [edit] but to make changes to your question to improve it.